# how to login using google on laravel breeze and next js. and get auth middleware on next js

Tags: javascript, laravel, next.js, google-signin, breeze

controller in laravel breeze

```
public function handleAuthCallback(): JsonResponse
{
    
        /** @var SocialiteUser $socialiteUser */
    try {
        $socialiteUser = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
    } catch (ClientException $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid credentials provided.'], 422);
    }
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = User::query()
        ->firstOrCreate(
            [
                'email' => $socialiteUser->getEmail(),
            ],
            [
                'email_verified_at' => now(),
                'name' => $socialiteUser->getName(),
                'google_id' => $socialiteUser->getId(),
                'password' => Hash::make(Str::random(40))
            ]
        );
    event(new Registered($user));
    
    Auth::login($user);
    
    
    
    return response()->json([
        'user' => $user,
        'access_token' => $user->createToken('google-token')->plainTextToken,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
    ]);
}
```

in nextjs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
function google() {
const Router = useRouter()
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
const [data, setData] = useState({})
const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

// On page load, we take "search" parameters
// and proxy them to /api/auth/callback on our Laravel API
const p = Router.asPath
const q = p.split('?', 2)
const query = q[q.length - 1]
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/login/google/callback?${query}`, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Accept: 'application/json',
        },
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then(data => {
            setLoading(false)
            setData(data)
        })
    // .then(data =>
    // )
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('tb:user', JSON.stringify(data))
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
})
// Helper method to fetch User data for authenticated user
// Watch out for "Authorization" header that is added to this call
function fetchUserData() {
    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/user`, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Accept: 'application/json',
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + data.access_token,
        },
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then(data => {
            setUser(data)
        })
}

if (loading) {
    return <DisplayLoading />
} else {
    if (user != null) {
        return <DisplayData data={user} />
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <DisplayData data={data} />
                <div style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
                    <button onClick={fetchUserData}>Fetch User</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
}

function DisplayLoading() {
return <div>Loading....</div>
}

function DisplayData(data) {
return (
    <div>
        <samp>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</samp>
    </div>
)
}

export default google
```

how to get middleware auth in nextjs.. because when i login, not have a user
how to get middleware auth in nextjs.. because when i login, not have a user
how to get middleware auth in nextjs.. because when i login, not have a user
how to get middleware auth in nextjs.. because when i login, not have a user